# Number of involutions by combinatorial

Tags: involutions

Let $_$ be the number of involutions in $\sigma_n$. Show that $_0 = _1 = 1$ and for $ \geq 2$
$_ = _{−1} + ( − 1)_{−2}.$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be an involution on $\{1,2,...,n\}$.

Then, only two things could happen with $f(n)$:

- Either $f(n)=n$ and $f$ restricts to an involution on $\{1,2,...,n-1\}$, or
- $f(n) \ne n$ and $f$ restricts to an involution on $\{1,2,...,n-1\} \setminus \{f(n)\}$.

In the first case, there are $i_{n-1}$ involutions on $\{1,2,...,n-1\}$, each of which induces an involution on $\{1,2,...,n\}$ that fixes $n$.

In the second case, there are $n-1$ possible choices for $f(n)$, and each involution on the remaining $n-2$ elements (of which there are $i_{n-2}$ of them) induces an involution on $\{1,2,...,n\}$ that does not fix $n$.

So, $i_n=i_{n-1}+(n-1)i_{n-2}$.

There is just one involution on the empty set or on any singleton set (namely, the identity map), so $i_0=i_1=1$.

Comment: Fine work, but It's better not to give a full answer to somebody that has shown no personal work...